# how to change putty's default color for the directory?

Tags: putty, color-theme

I find some better looking color themes for putty, but the default coloring for the directory names are just anoying as you can see below, it makes me so hard to see the name of those directories, how can I change the background color for the directory names??

[image]

**================================================================

edit:**

the post jack refers is really great, it takes me to the right direction.
Just want to add some more information related to my problem in case someone came across the same issue:

the green ugly background in my case is caused by that I'm ssh into an ubuntu virtual machine managed by vagrant, so I have some synced directory between the host OS and guest OS. those directories are of the type "ow" categoried by `LS_COLORS`, so according to the post, I put this line `at the bottom( must be the last line )` in my zshrc, then everything works fine now!!

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ow=34;40:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those colours are based on the permissions of the folders, I believe those colours on the default colour scheme indicate full permissions.

The colour scheme is actually built into the ls command, not putty. For more information on how to change those colours see this [good post here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find [here](http://swimminginthought.com/putty-ssh-dark-blue-directory-listing-unreadable-quick-fix/) a good solution.